# Spectral entropy of a signal in Python

Tags: python-3.x, entropy

I wish to find spectral entropy of below sinusoidal signal:

```
## Impprt the libraries
import numpy as np
import entropy as ent


Fs = 100               ## Sampling frequency (Hz)
f = 1                  ## frequency of sine signal(Hz)
T = 4                  ## Duration(s)
N = Fs * T             ## Total number of discrete samples
t = np.arange(N) / Fs  ## Time vector
x = np.sin(2 * np.pi * Fs * t)
np.round(ent.spectral_entropy(x, sf, method='fft'), 2)
```

However, I am getting below error:

**AttributeError: module 'entropy' has no attribute 'spectral_entropy'**

Can somebody please let me know how to eliminate the error ?

Comment: Which library (and version) of entropy are you using?

Comment: I installed entropy from here: https://pypi.org/project/entropy/

Comment: The link you gave suggests this is a command line tool, rather than a python library. This seems to have the method you want: https://github.com/raphaelvallat/antropy